# [android]Error import existing project into other computer

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I import the file into my other computer and it appears like this. It run properly in my previous computer. I am using this method

1. File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace,   Next
   Select root directory: /path/to/project Projects-> Select All 
   UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to
   working sets" Finish

==================================================================================
I get this error:

- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project
- The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- Unable to resolve target 'android-7'

[image]

Comment: Is the ADK and ADT all setup correctly?

Comment: Do you have the Android API7 present in your eclipse?

Comment: I install API 7 and it run eventually. I had installed the newest version only.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common problem. this might be because , your project's .class file is in readonly mode when you move it to the another computer. I suggest you to delete that .class file from the project and clean the project , then run it, it will surely solve your problem.

Comment: where is the .class file? do you mean all my file in src?

Comment: Your .class files will be in the bin folder of your project

Answer (score 0):

for "unable to resolve target" error you might double check the following:

- Do you have Android2.1 or your specific android library in your project? If not, right click on your project->properties->Android (from left side of dialog)-> Select Android 2.1(or other version) as the Project build Target (from right side of the dialog).
- Also, make sure project.properties file contains target target=android-7(or your version).
- Also,check if "uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion" contains the correct version in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if your JRE is not configured in project built path.

To configure JRE:

In Eclipse:

1. Right click on your project and select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
2. Go to Libraries tab click Add Library.
3. Select JRE System Library and related Android Library click Next
4. Then select JRE from options as per your requirement. Click Finish